# How to access BOM(Browser Object Model) in browser's console?

Tags: html, dom

If BOM(Browser Object Model) exists then why I can't access it from the console.

> Browser

has no effect. But DOM(Document Object Model) can be accessed using

> Document

Why is that? Does it really exist? Shouldn't we be able to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BOM isn't really a tangible thing - from wikipedia:

> The **Browser Object Model (BOM)** is a browser-specific convention
>   referring to all the objects exposed by the web browser. Unlike the
>   Document Object Model, there is no standard for implementation and no
>   strict definition, so browser vendors are free to implement the BOM in
>   any way they wish.

The closest thing I could suggest to 'access' it is via `window`